# It appears you are running a x server NVIDIA Drivers 304.02 Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, nvidia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install NVIDIA.run?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149206/how-to-install-nvidia-run)

So I went to NVIDIA's site and I saw they had a version with a lot of bug fixes. http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/49073

and I downloaded it, I ran the .run file rooted. It keeps saying "It appears you are running a x server" I don't have any current NVIDIA driver installed, I tried the nvidia x-config thing but that didn't work. It just says it can't be found. Should I wait until that version gets on Ubuntu's software center? I don't feel like installing their old and bad version of the drivers.

Comment: 64 Bit version btw...

Comment: Oops... 304.51 actual video card driver version...

Answer (score 0):

manual instructions are posted here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaManual

But, as indicated on the wiki page, in general it is best to install the restricted driver from the repository

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Is there some reason or feature that you feel you need in the latest driver ? Are you having a problem with the open source driver (nouveau) or the binary in the repositories ?