# Black screen after boot (after installing nvidia drivers)

Tags: nvidia, 12.10, laptop

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my old laptop.
I downloaded new nVidia drivers that released yesterday (my Vcard is 7000M) and installed it as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/149224/106184) .
After rebooting, I see for 1 second login promt and then black screen with cursor, but I can't type anything.
I removed nvidia drivers in safemode, but problem doesn't solved.
What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it worked for me (problem with lightdm)

ctrl+alt+f1. Login and do a restart lightdm

then i could log in to desktop and do : gedit /etc/rc.local
before the "exit 0" line  insert this line:  service restart lightdm

It worked for me, and i hope it'll work for you

Comment: I've already reinstalled Ubuntu, but anyway thank you.