# Ubuntu 12.04 - Nvidia Geforce 210 Driver install - "Error" xserver running

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, xserver

i've been trying to update my Nvidia driver, but I keep getting errors. As im quite new to ubuntu.

The following is the install log:

```
Using: nvidia-installer ncurses user interface
-> The file '/tmp/.X0-lock' exists and appears to contain the process ID '1196' of a runnning X server.
ERROR: You appear to be running an X server; please exit X before installing.  For further details, 
please see the section INSTALLING THE NVIDIA DRIVER in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  
You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

Comment: how did you install the nvidia driver? from the nvidia website?

Comment: install nvidia drivers through the "additional drivers" app in the dash. [See here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Valve/#Driver_Upgrades). Don't install them via nvidias website.

Comment: I got an error after the install, no matter which driver i chose of the "additional drivers" app, but i managed to work it out. I followed the "guide" located here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/149206/how-to-install-nvidia-run