# Linux on Asus ROG Laptop

Tags: system-installation, asus

I'm a Linux enthusiast, and I'm about to buy an Asus Republic of Gamers laptop.  Does anyone know about installation issues or broken features in these laptops?

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Ubuntu 14.10 in a G751.

There was only one problem during install, and is easily solved booting with the nomodeset option.

May be this info could be useful to you or others:

Create a Live USB with starup disk creator or UNetbootin.
Turn on your g751 and press esc to see the boot menu, then select your usb drive.
When you see the grub menu, move the cursor to "try ubuntu..." (I choose try ubuntu, so I can partition my drive with gparted) press e to edit the boot options and add add "nomodeset" after "quiet splash" and press F10 to boot.

Install and reboot, when you are on grub screen, press e again to change to add the nomodeset option. After you boot your system for first time you can make the nomodeset option permanent. Edit the grub file using -

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

add "nomodeset" after "quiet splash" and save

```
sudo update-grub
```

Go to nvidia.com and download the lastest drivers.Then press ctrl+alt+F1 to see tty1 login in that console kill the x server and run the nvidia installation script, but first you'll need to give execution permission to that file.

```
sudo service lightdm stop (kill x server)
cd ~/Downloads (or where you downloaded your file)
chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.35.run (file downloaded from nvidia web page)
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.35.run
```

reboot when finish.

More info:

[How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu)

[What does `nomodeset` do](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do?rq=1)

http://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?54491-Installing-Arch-Linux-on-my-G751-JY

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/nvidia-343-22-install-in-ubuntu-1404/

[How to install NVIDIA.run?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149206/how-to-install-nvidia-run)

Comment: You saved my day J.Serra. I was able to boot a Live USB with Ubuntu 16.04 (formatted with Rufus) in a Republic of Gamers GL702V. The error I was getting was "ignoring bgrt failed to map image memory".

Answer (score 2):

I am currently running ubuntu 14.10 on a ASUS G751. So far most things work. You need a new NVIDIA driver that supports the GPU, look here:

[How to use NVIDIA GTX 970 GPU?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/561295/how-to-use-nvidia-gtx-970-gpu)

Here is a guide that might help you avoid any boot issues:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Once I installed ubuntu I got the following message while trying to boot:

```
/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod not found
```

This guide helped me figure out that problem:

https://superuser.com/questions/376470/how-to-reinstall-grub2-efi

Here is a guide how to make the "steam" key working:

[How to make the "Steam key" on ASUS ROG laptop work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572993/how-to-make-the-steam-key-on-asus-rog-laptop-work)

Hope this is helpful. I regret not writing down what I did to make this work.