# Has xorg deleted the nvidia 343 package?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, xorg, ppa

I'm following [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/566375/373354) answer to get my GTX 970 working, however before installing nvidia-343 I noticed that I couldn't find the package on xorgs site:
https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

I'd like to know what I'm doing rather than blindly follow solutions which may be out of date, can anyone shed some light onto this and educate me :)?

Thank you

Comment: I asume you did read the description of the PPA and clearly understand is not mean for daily use?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  

I did read every warning (repeatedly since the launchpad page implies heavily the importance of understanding it).

I have yet to get my video card working so I am indeed doing this just as an experiment.

Comment: It has been removed, but that still leaves **340** and **346**. Check output from: **`sudo apt-cache search "NVIDIA binary driver"`**

Comment: Thank you very much David, that helped me greatly to know my assessment was correct rather than blindly guessing.  Sadly both of these resulted in booting to a blank screen but luckily I am doing this all in a separate ubuntu partition/install.  You should put your response as an answer so I can accept it, it fully addresses my initial concern (and possibly will help others who follow my path)

Answer (score 0):

It has been removed, but that still leaves 340 and 346. Check output from:

```
sudo apt-cache search "NVIDIA binary driver"
```