# Unity problem? missing launch bar and severe flickering of windows/icons

Tags: unity, flicker

what works:

```
- background wallpaper is shown correctly
- mouse seems to behave normally
```

what doesn't work:

```
- none of the launch bars is visible
- desktop icons flicker between their correct position and
  a place just a bit to the left and down
- open windows flicker, moving down a bit each time
  upon hitting the bottom monitor border, they stop moving but continue flickering
- right-click menu is placed correctly but briefly turns invisible while flicker occurs
- all flickering seems to occur in a one second interval
```

System:

```
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (freshly installed on previously blank drive)
- Processor: Intel i7-6700K
- Graphics: NVidia GTX970
- Mainboard: MSI Z170A
```

The PC has no network connection right now, so i am unable to download/install packages...

If any other information is useful, please say so.

Comment: You may need to install the Nvidia proprietary drivers. Read this: [How to use NVIDIA GTX 970 GPU?](http://askubuntu.com/a/567483). You'd need to download some files, but you could transfer them with a USB stick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I found out, that I fell victim to the following bug:

[bugs.launchpad.net->llvm-toolchain-bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/llvm-toolchain-3.8/+bug/1564156)

**Summarized:** The version of the package **libllvm3.8** which is distributed with Ubuntu 16.04 crashes on certain mixes of NVidia GPUs and Skylake CPUs. This is already fixed for later versions of the package.

Therefore a simple update as done below should fix the problem in 99% of cases.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever figure out what the problem was? This exact behavior just started happening to me since the latest update on 16.04. I don't know if this helps, but going through

> /var/log/apt/history.log

it seems that the latest update (which caused the problem) changed the following packages

```
snapd
gnome-shell-common
libnm-gtk-common
network-manager-gnome
libnma0
libnma-common
libnm-gtk0
```

So I guess that one of these is causing the problem. I'll try reverting to a previous version for each of these packages one by one to see if it helps.

Hope you sorted it out on your end, if not I hope that this may help you...

Have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting this and I figure it might be related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1898743) especially since someone commented *"This appears to happen after xscreensaver runs, but only some times. I don't see any pattern to which times."* and it happened to me after the screensaver had run I think.

Restarting unity by pressing `Alt+F2` then typing `unity` then `Enter` fixed the flicker temporarily, but this is only slightly better than rebooting, as it closes all open windows.