# How to run Ubuntu with GTX970?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I've used Ubuntu with my Laptop for many years and I just wanted to switch my desktop PC to Ubuntu. I couldn't. (16.10)

I find out Linux has a problem with Nvidia cards. I've tried every solution that is on the net. They did not work. 
I've removed my graphics card and managed to install Ubuntu and it worked properly but I need my graphics card installed. What should I do? Any suggestions?

Comment: If you have tried every solution you wouldn't be here. You need nomodeset until the proprietary drivers are installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @CelticWarrior on the comments, you need to put your graphic card back and then install Ubuntu with `nomodeset`, here is how you do that:

- The moment your computer start reading from the installation media(i.e CD, USB or whatever you are using to install Ubuntu):

[image: img1]

you need to press and hold  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  or  <kbd>Enter</kbd> , this should bring up a screen similar to this:

[image: select language]

- Go ahead and select your language then press  <kbd>Enter</kbd> .

[image: this]:[1]]

- Next you need to press  <kbd>F6</kbd>
- At this point you can use the  <kbd>Up</kbd>  and  <kbd>Down</kbd>  keys to move up and down. You need to select `nomodeset` and press  <kbd>Enter</kbd> .
- At this point you can simply click on Install Ubuntu and you should be able to install Ubuntu without any issues.

Note that when you login for the first time, the graphics might not be good, you will need to install proprietary drivers. You do this as follows:

- click on **System** :

[image: click1]

- Click on **Additional Drivers**:
  [image]

If you need more details on how to install drivers, head over [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers).

PS: If you want GPU support, have look at the answers supplied [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/561295/476968),  [or here](https://askubuntu.com/q/451221/476968) :
Let me know if that helps :).