# Problems updating kernel to 4.8+ on 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: 16.04, kernel, 16.10

I have a 6700k and 1080 gtx card so I was told to install Nvidia drivers 370.28 which I did and I also followed a couple guides to install kernel 4.8, 4.8.5, 4.9rc2 and every time I reboot the computer I get a system failure message with Ubuntu login page, when I try logging into Ubuntu it just loops the page and I end up having to reinstall Ubuntu again. I've spent 12 hours trying to get this to work to no avail.

As the last kernel guide I tried this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CokrHUykkUQ).

I've also tried installing 16.10 to skip this kernel problem but there I have a completely different problem where the mouse doesn't work during install.

Comment: Hi @mordec4i, Have you tried installing ubuntu with `nomodeset` enabled: http://askubuntu.com/a/839658/476968 ?

Comment: you mean for the 16.10 install? I can install 16.04 just fine but after upgrading the kernel I can't log into the system due to system failure.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Yakkety Yakk kernel 4.8.0.25 like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-kernel-team/ppa

sudo apt update

sudo apt install linux-image-generic-lts-yakkety
```

This will allow any updates to come to you via the software updater.

If you don't like it, you can uninstall it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge (If you don't have it)

sudo apt purge linux-image-generic-lts-yakkety

sudo ppa-purge ppa:canonical-kernel-team/ppa
```

I've been using it for some time now with no problems.

Hope this helps.