# How to make the "Steam key" on ASUS ROG laptop work

Tags: scripts, laptop, asus, steam, shortcut-keys

The dedicated steam key on my ASUS ROG G751 laptop does not do anything. What do I need to do to make it launch steam?

Comment: Please add more details.

Comment: I answered my own question. I hope that explains what I was asking for.

Comment: Also added laptop name to question.

Answer (score 1):

Update: This will make the "video" button and the "rog" button next to the keypad also launch steam. Will look into that when I have the time.

This is how I made the "Steam button" work on my ASUS ROG G751. I would not be surprised if there is a simpler way to do this :) I am using **xbindkeys** to bind the steam key to a script. The script will start steam if it is not already running. If steam is running the script will change focus to steam. To achieve this I am using **xdotool**.

Install xbindkeys:

```
sudo apt-get xbindkeys    
sudo apt-get xbindkeys-config    
xbindkeys --defaults > ~/.xbindkeysrc
```

Run:

```
xbindkeys-config
```

Add a new item with:
Name: **Steam**,
Key: **Mod2 + NoSymbol | m:0x10 + c:248**, or you can use the "Get Key" function.
We want to execute a script as Action: **~/opensteam**
This script will start steam if not started. Change focus to steam if started.

Install xdomod

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

Script (opensteam):

```
nano ~/opensteam
```

Enter this into nano:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -n "$(tail /var/log/kern.log -n 1 | grep 'key 7f pressed')" ]; then
 if [ -z "$(xdotool search --name steam)" ]; then
  echo "Focus"
  steam &
 else
  echo "Execute"
  xdotool search --name steam windowactivate
 fi
else
 echo "Steam key was not pressed"
fi
```

Make opensteam executable

```
chmod a+x opensteam
```

Open "startup applications" either via the menu or via command:

```
gnome-session-properties
```

In startup applications add:
Name, command and comment: **xbindkeys**

This will make the xbindkeys launch when you log in. It runs in the background.

Edit: Added a nasty hack to fix the issue where the ROG key and the video key also started steam.