# Strange messages after running `sudo service lightdm stop`

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, lightdm, cuda, xserver

I'm trying to install CUDA and the NVIDIA drivers on my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop. Following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149206/how-to-install-nvidia-run), I entered `CTRL+ALT+F1`, and then `sudo service lightdm stop`, in order to disable the X server. On previous machines, this has worked fine. However, on this occasion, I get a bunch of messages which I do not understand:

[image]

I've tried rebooting, and the same happens. The strange thing is, this is a completely fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04. All I have done is installed a few standard packages (e.g. `git`, `build-essential`, `cmake`), and then downloaded the CUDA / NVIDIA `.run` file, then ran `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*`, and then did the above.

Any ideas on what is going on?