# Unable to login to Ubuntu 16.04 after stopping X server

Tags: 16.04, lightdm, xserver

I was following the top answer from this link:
[How to install NVIDIA.run?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149206/how-to-install-nvidia-run?newreg=82e37b2549d84837adf268e21196a4c7)

As per instruction I stopped X server and now I am unable to login to Ubuntu. When I boot up it brings me to my login but after typing my password and entering it freezes without showing the unity bar.

I tried booting up in recovery mode but it is unable to. I used CTL alt f3 to try starting lightdm but that fails too.

I have dual boot installed on my Asus Zenbook so reinstalling ubuntu is an option but I only want to do it as a last resort.

Edit: some additional information, the installation when running the nvidia.run file failed so I followed through the instructions to restart the computer.
Ctrl + alt + f3 Will hang the computer on its login screen.

Comment: Update: I have decided to reinstall ubuntu 16.04 since most of my work is on the cloud.