# NVIDIA driver not loaded on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I installed nvidia driver by:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-390
```

But it looks like the driver isn't running properly:

```
$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

I've checked the kernel module by `lsmod | nvidia` but failed to find it.

Here's the output for `lshw` and `lspci`, hoping it could help:

```
$ lspci
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
...
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)

$ lshw -C display                                                                                                                             0s 
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: 3D controller
       product: GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f2000000-f2ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:6000(size=128)
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:29 memory:f3000000-f33fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:7000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

Rebooting, disabling Secure Boot and `prime-select nvidia` all have no effect.

I'm using `Ubuntu 18.04` with `4.18.0-16-generic`. Thanks for your advices!

Comment: At login you aren't selecting the wayland option (under the gear icon) are you?  Wayland will automatically switch to the intel driver. Why use a ppa for the 390 driver, it is in the standard repos.

Comment: I'm using xorg instead of wayland. I noticed that there's a package called xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390 in the standard repo, is this the correct one?

Comment: That's the nvidia driver package, but I usually recommend getting the nvidia set up through the Software and Updates/Additional Drivers tab -- select the 390 driver.

Comment: It looks like my device is pretty old, the Additional Driver tab only lists 340.107. But the CUDA needs newer driver so I have to install the 390 one, which is the newest driver that support my GPU architecture. xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390 alone seems have no effect. I didn't see any error during my installation from ppa.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you found a solution but only Nvidia 304 works for older cards 
but installing 304 gives you dependency issues

So you follow the instructions on this AskUbuntu question
[Can't install Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080868/cant-install-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04)

and patch up the installer from Nvidia and run it. It worked for me.