# Ubuntu won't boot after installing nvidia-304

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, lightdm

I've installed nvidia-304 driver following the answer on this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080868/cant-install-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04?answertab=votes#tab-top).

After installing the NVidia driver and rebooting, my Ubuntu will not boot anymore. It gets stuck at "Starting Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures...".

From all instructions above, only "sudo service lightdm stop" failed with error "lightdm.service not loaded". I thought it was OK to ignore this.

Any thoughts?

My hardware configuration is:

- HP Pavilion dv6000 / AMD64
- 00:12.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA
  Corporation C67 [GeForce 7150M / nForce 630M] (rev a2)

Comment: Does it work with open-source drivers? Keep it that way, it's not you're gonna play games with that hatdware ;)

Comment: It kinda works, but it is very unstable. I had to change to a basic color background. Sometimes the display won't come back from back screen timeout, or even if I close and open the lid or if I remotely log in via Teamviewer. Only rebooting Ubuntu would "fix" it.

Comment: Oh well... If the only version of Nvidia drivers supporting your card is no longer available the usual way, the method you used may or may not work.