# Installation of Nvidia driver 304.317 on Lubuntu 16.04/18.04 failed

Tags: 16.04, drivers, 18.04, nvidia, lubuntu

I tried to install the Nvidia driver 304.317 according this post:
[Can't install Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080868/cant-install-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04/1085486#1085486)

During installation, several errors occurred:

Error message 1:

```
ERROR: Failed to run '/usr/sbin/dkms build -m nvidia -v 304.137 -k 5.0.0-23-generic':
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel. Skipping ...
Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j2 KERNELRELEASE=5.0.0-23-generic module SYSSRC=/lib/modules/5.0.0-23-generic/build...................(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for nvidia: 304.137 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.0.0-23-generic (i686)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/304.137/build/make.log for more information.
```

Error message 2:

```
ERROR: Failed to install the kernel module through DKMS.
No kernel module was installed: please try to installing again without DKMS, or check the DKMS logs for more information.
```

Error message 3:

```
ERROR: Installation has failed. Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log for details.
You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

nvidia-installer.log

```
nvidia-installer log file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log'
creation time: Sat Aug 10 21:13:58 2019
installer version: 304.137

PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin

nvidia-installer command line:
    ./nvidia-installer

Unable to load: nvidia-installer ncurses v6 user interface

Using: nvidia-installer ncurses user interface
-> License accepted.
-> Installing NVIDIA driver version 304.137.
-> Running distribution scripts
   executing: '/usr/lib/nvidia/pre-install'...
-> done.
-> The distribution-provided pre-install script failed!  Continue installation anyway? (Answer: Yes)
-> Would you like to register the kernel module sources with DKMS? This will allow DKMS to automatically build a new module, if you install a different kernel later. (Answer: Yes)
-> Installing both new and classic TLS OpenGL libraries.
-> Searching for conflicting X files:
-> done.
-> Searching for conflicting OpenGL files:
-> done.
-> Installing 'NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86' (304.137):
   executing: '/sbin/ldconfig'...
   executing: '/sbin/depmod -aq'...
   depmod: WARNING: Ignored deprecated option -q
-> done.
-> Driver file installation is complete.
-> Installing DKMS kernel module:
ERROR: Failed to run `/usr/sbin/dkms build -m nvidia -v 304.137 -k 5.0.0-23-generic`: 
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j2 KERNELRELEASE=5.0.0-23-generic module SYSSRC=/lib/modules/5.0.0-23-generic/build...................(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for nvidia: 304.137 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.0.0-23-generic (i686)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/304.137/build/make.log for more information.
-> error.
ERROR: Failed to install the kernel module through DKMS. No kernel module was installed; please try installing again without DKMS, or check the DKMS logs for more information.
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

make.log

```
DKMS make.log for nvidia-304.137 for kernel 5.0.0-23-generic (i686)
Sa 10. Aug 21:14:49 CEST 2019
NVIDIA: calling KBUILD...
Makefile:223: ================= WARNING ================
Makefile:224: 'SUBDIRS' will be removed after Linux 5.3
Makefile:225: Please use 'M=' or 'KBUILD_EXTMOD' instead
Makefile:226: ==========================================
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (        \
echo >&2;                           \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
echo >&2 ;                          \
/bin/false)
mkdir -p /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/304.137/build/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/304.137/build/.tmp_versions/*
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/304.137/build
(cat /dev/null;   echo kernel//var/lib/dkms/nvidia/304.137/build/nvidia.ko;) > /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/304.137/build/modules.order
[several compiler calls]
  cc -Wp,-MD,/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/304.137/build/.os-interface.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/7/include  -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -Iubuntu/include  -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -fno-PIE -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m32 -msoft-float -mregparm=3 -freg-struct-return -fno-pic -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -march=i686 -mtune=generic -Wa,-mtune=generic32 -ffreestanding -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SSSE3=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX512=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -fno-jump-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-frame-address -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format-overflow -Wno-int-in-bool-context -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fno-var-tracking-assignments -pg -mrecord-mcount -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fno-merge-all-constants -fmerge-constants -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -I/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/304.137/build -Wall -MD -Wsign-compare -Wno-cast-qual -Wno-error -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DNVRM -DNV_VERSION_STRING=\"304.137\" -Wno-unused-function -Wuninitialized -UDEBUG -U_DEBUG -DNDEBUG  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"os_interface"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"nvidia"' -c -o /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/304.137/build/os-interface.o /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/304.137/build/os-interface.c
[several compiler warnings -Wsign-compare]
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/304.137/build/os-interface.c: In function ‘os_get_current_time’:
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/304.137/build/os-interface.c:667:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘do_gettimeofday’; did you mean ‘efi_gettimeofday’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
     do_gettimeofday(&tm);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     efi_gettimeofday
[several compiler calls]
Makefile:1606: recipe for target '_module_/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/304.137/build' failed
make[2]: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/304.137/build] Error 2
NVIDIA: left KBUILD.
nvidia.ko failed to build!
Makefile:262: recipe for target 'module' failed
make[1]: *** [module] Error 1
makefile:59: recipe for target 'module' failed
make: *** [module] Error 2
```

I tried to install the driver without dkms, but I had the same problem. The readme from nvidia couldn't help me out. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

I set up 16.04 (which I had installed before my HDD crashed) and have the same problem. Doesn't matter if I install it with `ubuntu-dirivers autoinstall`, `apt-get install nvidia-304` or fully manual. Also if I try to install the previous version 304.135 (actual is 304.137). Before my HDD crashed, I had version 304.134 (because 304.135 made some problems) but it seems this version isn't in the repository any more. The nouveau driver works fine (with 16.04 and 18.04), even with a second screen, but the performance is miserable.

**Update**

After several test and attempts on both Lubuntu versions (16.04 and 18.04) and different nvidia-304 versions, I think the problem is the used compiler version which should be gcc-4.6 (can't find the link any more), 16.04 uses gcc-5.0, 18.04 uses gcc-7.4. I give up to install the proprietary driver due to high effort.
While my research, I recognized, the nouveau driver was never installed on the system. `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` won't install the nouveau driver. I installed manually (on 18.04) with `apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`, following packages were removed and the system was broken after installation:

```
lubuntu-desktop lubuntu-gtk-core lubuntu-gtk-desktop
xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-18.04
xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-18.04
xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-18.04
xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-18.04
xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-18.04
xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-18.04
xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-18.04
```

Comment: This is just a comment, Lubuntu 16.04 LTS is EOL as it is a flavor with only 3 years of support. The 5 years of support for 16.04 LTS applies to standard Unity desktop, Kylin & server (no desktop).  The last official Lubuntu release statement is https://lubuntu.me/xenial-5-released/ which notes support ends April 2019.

Answer (score 4):

I would **strongly recommend** you use the `ubuntu-drivers` tool instead. It is safer and will install the suitable **NVIDIA or nouveau** driver for your card.

However, you need to clean up and purge the current NVIDIA driver first by running the following in the terminal:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia-*
```

Then you can run the tool in the terminal like this:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Reboot your system after that for the changes to take effect.

**Notice:**

304.* is no longer supported by [NVIDIA](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3142/~/support-timeframes-for-unix-legacy-gpu-releases) and no releases are available for newer kernels `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` will install the `nouveau` driver which I think should have good enough support for such an old GPU.

If ,however, you must do it the way you describe in your question. You might need to take a look at your BIOS settings and disable **secure boot**. [source](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/908147/nvidia-linux-x86_64-352-63-run-install-problem/)

**An alternate option is to go back to Ubuntu 16.04:**

If you chose to do so, you may want to enable the **restricted** Ubuntu repository. You can do this from the software and updates options in the GUI or add the repository in the terminal as follows:

```
echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted" | sudo tee -a  /etc/apt/sources.list
```

After that update the apt packages list:

```
sudo apt update
```

Then install the driver like so:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

or

```
sudo apt install nvidia-304
```

or

Get the package at [nvidia-304_304.135-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/n/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304/nvidia-304_304.135-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb)

Comment: ubuntu-drivers doesn't work in this case, because nvidia-304 is not supported by 18.04. I have an old notebook without secure boot.

Comment: It is no longer supported by NVIDIA https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3142/~/support-timeframes-for-unix-legacy-gpu-releases and no releases available for newer kernels `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` will install the `nouveau` driver which I think should have good enough support for such an old GPU. Best of luck

Comment: `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` tries to install nvidia-304, but fails because of dependencies. nouveau is installed automatically after setting up Lubuntu.

Comment: @bestucki I added instructions for Ubuntu 16.04. Please have a look.