# Nvidia 304 driver installation

Tags: nvidia

I have installed Lubuntu 18.04 on an old Inspiron 9300 laptop. It runs okay with nouveau driver, but the application I need to work with requires the proprietary Nvidia driver.

I have tried to install Nvidia 304 driver on 18.04 but it doesn't build!
I also installed Ubuntu16.04 and tried the PPA driver installation with no success.
I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Any advice?

Comment: Why didn't you install https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/nvidia-340 from repositories?  Is there a reason you opted to build your own instead?  I would have tried `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` and let your Ubuntu do the work for you first, or did you try that and have reason to do it manually?  (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto)   (*Sorry i misread 304/340*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080868/cant-install-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: The 304 driver has to be patched to work, but even that doesn' t work with newer kernels. I got it to work using the information/comments in this bug report, but not with the HWE kernel. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304/+bug/1737750

Comment: The key information for patching the driver is here: https://adufray.com/blog/2018/06/02/nvidia-304-127-on-bionic

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions!  I guess that I should be more precise about the test i have already performed: on 18.04.1 kernel 5.3.0 i have tried driver from all sources ( Nvidia site, PPA ,.Adufray patch ...) No one install successfully.

Comment: In addition i have tested on 16.04 kernel 4.15 and installed PPA driver , but after reboot the xserver fail to start. Do i have to use an older kernel?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation. Rather than downgrading kernel I'm waiting for working patch 5.3+.  It would be cool to have a working patch that can be applied to extracted `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.137.run` archive. I found the blog post about a guy who implemented such a patch for Debian (can it be ported on ubuntu? and how? idk). [304 patch for 5+ kernels](http://blog.schmorp.de/2019-08-03-nvidia-legacy-304-patch-for-post-50-linux-kernels.html)