# Issues updating nVidia-driver-390 for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia

I have been trying to install nvidia-driver-390 for my graphics card **GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M]**.

Firstly, I tried to follow [these instructions](https://www.mvps.net/docs/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver-linux/). I go through the normal steps of adding the repo and updating my apt-get. But the driver I am looking for is not there.

So I looked into where I can find the correct driver [on nvidia.com](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/unix/). I can see nvidia-driver-390 and see my graphics card, Quadro K1100M, listed as supported. I download the `.run` file and use the instruction provided at [How to install NVIDIA.run?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149206/how-to-install-nvidia-run) and similar one [here on Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1916961) to install it. My pre-install fails with the details of `/var/log/nvidia-installer.log` as given below:

```
zero@knowzero:/var/log$ more nvidia-installer.log 
nvidia-installer log file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log'
creation time: Sun May 24 11:38:28 2020
installer version: 390.132

PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/u
sr/local/games

nvidia-installer command line:
    ./nvidia-installer

Unable to load: nvidia-installer ncurses v6 user interface

Using: nvidia-installer ncurses user interface
-> Detected 8 CPUs online; setting concurrency level to 8.
-> Installing NVIDIA driver version 390.132.
-> Running distribution scripts
   executing: '/usr/lib/nvidia/pre-install'...
-> done.
-> The distribution-provided pre-install script failed!  Are you sure you want t
o continue? (Answer: Abort installation)
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.
log' for details.  You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in t
he README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

How can I sort this out? I do have the option of ***continuing*** with my installation or ***abort*** it. I aborted to not do something that would make my computer unusable.

Edit: Just to clarify, the only reason I was using `.run` file was because when I did

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-3
```

and pressed <kbd>Tab</kbd>, I did not get the driver listed. So I thought it is somehow not there in the repository. But when I restarted and tried it again, it worked. I do not know what went wrong initially but it's fine. Seems like I jumped the gun.

Comment: I have `nvidia-driver-390` installed with no problems. Rhere was no need to download `.run` files.

Comment: What flavour of Ubuntu are you using and what release number?

Comment: gys, my bad...i explain y mistake in the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 390 driver is in the official Ubuntu repositories.

It can be installed by

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390
```

I can't understand what is the problem. Installing from `.run` files is wrong for Ubuntu

Comment: I added my naswer in the edit to the post...thank you for the reply