# Ubuntu Server 20.04 Nvidia Driver Dependencies

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I had a hard time installing Nvidia drivers in a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.  Installing via `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-430` resulted in a list of 542 packages to install.  I ended up spending a bit of manual effort to get the Nvidia-provided driver installed without nearly so many dependencies (only had to install `gcc` and `make`).

Is this massive number of dependencies normal for Ubuntu Server?  I did a very vanilla install without the GUI.  Reddit suggested I ask here, as their opinion is that I should just install from the default repos, but I felt that so many packages was absurd just to install a driver.

Edit for clarity: installing the `nvidia-driver-430` package appears to install the entire Gnome shell, which I feel is unnecessary on a server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can install headless version of an Nvidia driver with the following command:

`apt install nvidia-headless-440-server nvidia-utils-440-server`

Answer (score 0):

I personally recommend you follow this. This is absolutely a time saver for installing these graphics drivers.

Source of this info: [here](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/unix/)

**Install NVIDIA Graphics Driver via runfile**

Initially remove all the previous Nvidia drivers (Important)

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*

# Note this might remove your cuda installation as well
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Download the required driver from [Nvidia website](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/unix/)

**Install dependenices**

For Ubuntu, installing the following dependencies is enough.

1) `build-essential` -- For building the driver

2) (Optional) gcc-multilib -- For providing 32-bit support

3) `dkms` -- For providing dkms support

As a summary, All the above packages can be installed using this command `sudo apt-get install build-essential gcc-multilib dkms`

**Create Backlist for Nouveau driver**

Create a file at `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf` with the following contents:

```
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

Then,

for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, reboot the computer;

for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, excute `sudo update-initramfs -u` and reboot the computer;

**Stop lightdm/gdm/kdm**

After the computer is rebooted. We need to stop the desktop manager before excuting the runfile to install the driver. `lightdm` is the default desktop manager in Ubuntu. If GNOME or KDE desktop environment is used, installed desktop manager will then be `gdm` or `kdm`.

For Ubuntu 14.04 / 16.04, excuting `sudo service lightdm sto`p (or use gdm or kdm instead of lightdm)

For Ubuntu 16.04, excuting `sudo systemctl stop lightdm` (or use gdm or kdm instead of lightdm)

**Excuting the Runfile**

Enter the tty and enter these commands to execute the file

```
cd ~
chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-384.69.run
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-384.69.run --dkms -s
```

These errors can be safe to ignore

```
WARNING: nvidia-installer was forced to guess the X library path '/usr/lib' and X module path '/usr/lib/xorg/modules'; these paths were not queryable from the system.  If X fails to find the NVIDIA X driver module, please install the `pkg-config` utility and the X.Org SDK/development package for your distribution and reinstall the driver.
```

**Check the Installation**

After a succesful installation, `nvidia-smi` command will report all your CUDA-capable devices in the system.

Hope this helps

Comment: This looks like a link only answer. Please expand it by including an explanation and essential steps.

Comment: The first method, installing via apt-get, includes the gnome shell and all its dependencies.  This is what resulted in about 550 packages to install.  This being a server, I did not want to install all those packages or the shell in general.  What did work was the .run installation method, but that results in a driver that has to be reinstalled occasionally due to kernel update packages, and isn't in a repo for regular updates.

Comment: If you get an error, "ERROR: You appear to be running an X server; please exit X before installing.", check out https://askubuntu.com/questions/149206/how-to-install-nvidia-run