# DEPEND Dependency failed for Hyper-V KVP Protocol Daemon.ices-virtual-misc-vmbus\x21hv_kvp.device

Tags: boot, nvidia, dependencies, gpu, hyper-v

I was trying to enable GPU for tensorflow and I ended up with reinstalling GPU drivers, but I messed up the system. The computer (Ubuntu 18.04) does not open now. When I reboot it says:

```
[TIME] Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-CAB8F5E2B8F5CD47.device.ice.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /mnt/Fantom
```

Sometimes when I reboot it gives a similar error:

```
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Hyper-V KVP Protocol Daemon.ices-virtual-misc-vmbus\x21hv_kvp.device.
```

Fantom is my external hard drive's name. I cannot type anything or open the command line using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. If I wait like hours it pops up an error saying that `The system is running in low graphics mode` and gives 4 options, but I cannot click or choose any of them. I also tried pressing the <kbd>Shift</kbd> button while opening, but it did not open the GNU GRUB menu.

I was basically following the steps here :

[How to install NVIDIA.run?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149206/how-to-install-nvidia-run)

When I reboot the system at step 5, I started to get these errors.

Thanks in advance!

depend:

[image]

low graphics error:

[image]

depend 2:

[image]

depend 3:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with following steps:

- Make a bootable usb for Ubuntu
- Select USB as the first boot option in the BIOS menu
- While rebooting it goes into GNU GRUB menu
- Select recovery mode for the version of Ubuntu in which you get this error
- Select 'dpkg' - repair broken packages
- Select 'failsafeX'
- Once you can open the desktop, you can reboot to exit safe mode.