# I need to install an old driver, need to know how

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel

Running Ubuntu 16.04 on a HP with AMD Athlon(tm) II X2 220 Processor × 2, NVIDIA Corporation C61 [GeForce 6150SE nForce 430] (rev a2) card.

After update, I was stuck in the endless login loop. The latest version of the Nvidia driver doesn't work in my oh-so old Hewlett Packard.

Installing via `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` installs driver 304.137 which doesn't work.

I need driver 304.134, for which I have the .run file sitting in my desktop.

However, in order to access my computer, I had to purge everything related to Nvidia (only way to avoid login loop). I now am typing in 640x480 resolution and a bunch of squares with circles on the monitor:

[image]

I need help with the terminal commands to do the following:

1. Install the Nvidia 304.134 driver, in a system that has been freshly purged of everything Nvidia*

Comment: according to the supported products tab here (https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/123709/en-us) your card is still supported perhaps you just had a failed driver install? ether way you can dl the driver you want here(https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/112990/en-us) and this link has some install instructions for you (https://askubuntu.com/questions/149206/how-to-install-nvidia-run)

Comment: @wraith3690001  I started everything again, purged Nvidia, added repository graphics drivers, installed Nvidia-340. And then I noticed two errors in terminal, which I'm sure are the key to fixing this, if I knew what I am doing:
`ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-304.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.4.0-193-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-304/304.137/build/make.log for more information.` Any suggestions?

Comment: When viewing /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-304/304.137/build/make.log the output says ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";  \ echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.

Comment: @wraith3690001 the make.log file also has a bunch of "Werrors", about 50.